# where we can use tc class, tc qdisc and tc filter.?

Tags: linux-kernel, centos6

i have to control the bandwidth of a network with the help of tc class, tc qdisc and tc filter.
I don't know anything about this.
can anyone help for this ??

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, please visit http://www.lartc.org/. Download the manual and start off. 
Traffic Control utility( shortly called tc) is provided by lartc and most distro's have it by default. tc is sophisticated and I am sure spending time on that will help u solve your problem.